# Travelling Sales Man (need to visit only subset of nodes): Bugged

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I need help with my travelling sales man problem code. Its bugged... I know because its a school assignment and there are test cases. So here it goes.

Given a connected graph where I need to visit a subset of nodes. How do I compute the shortest path?

[image]

As an example, refer to above image. I need to start from 0 and visit some/all nodes then go back to zero. In the process, I need to compute the shortest path.

Suppose I need to visit all nodes, I will go from `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0` = `20 + 30 + 12 + 35 = 97`. Suppose now I only need to visit node 2, I will go from `0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0` as that gives shortest path of 94 (I can visit nodes I don't have to visit if it can give a shortest path).

Basically, I did:

1. Compute shortest path between any 2 pairs of required nodes and the source (0). This gives me a shortest path 2D table like (I used dijkstra's):

   ```
     |  0  1  2  3
   --+--------------
   0 | 
   1 |
   2 | 
   3 |
   ```
2. Now, I modify the shopping sales man algorithm (aka. Floyd Warshall’s or APSP) to use this table. Current Java source (TSP and dijkstra's) looks like:

   ```
   int TSP(int source, int visited) {
      if (visited == (int)(Math.pow(2, K)-1)) { // all required visited
       return sssp.get(source).get(0); // return to source (0)
     } else if (memo.containsKey(source) && memo.get(source).containsKey(visited)) {
       return memo.get(source).get(visited);
     } else {
       int item;
       if (!memo.containsKey(source)) {
         memo.put(source, new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
       }
       memo.get(source).put(visited, 1000000);
       for (int v = 0; v < K; v++) {
         item = shoppingList[v];
         if (!hasVisited(visited, item)) {
           memo.get(source).put(visited, Math.min(
             memo.get(source).get(visited),
             sssp.get(source).get(item) + TSP(item, visit(visited, v))
           ));
         }
       }
       return memo.get(source).get(visited);
     }
   }

   int dijkstra(int src, int dest) {
     PriorityQueue<IntegerPair> PQ = new PriorityQueue<IntegerPair>();
     HashMap<Integer, Integer> dist = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); // shortest known dist from {src} to {node}
     // init shortest known distance
     for (int i = 0; i < N+1; i++) {
       if (i != src) {
         dist.put(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE); // dist to any {i} is big(unknown) by default
       } else {
         dist.put(src, 0); // dist to {src} is always 0
       }
     }
     IntegerPair node;
     int nodeDist;
     int nodeIndex;

     PQ.offer(new IntegerPair(0, src)); 
     while (PQ.size() > 0) {
       node = PQ.poll();
       nodeDist = node.first();
       nodeIndex = node.second();

       if (nodeDist == dist.get(nodeIndex)) {
         // process out going edges
         for (int v = 0; v < N+1; v++) { // since its a complete graph, process all edges
           if (v != nodeIndex) { // except curr node
             if (dist.get(v) > dist.get(nodeIndex) + T[nodeIndex][v]) { // relax if possible
               dist.put(v, dist.get(nodeIndex) + T[nodeIndex][v]);
               PQ.offer(new IntegerPair(dist.get(v), v));
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
     return dist.get(dest);
   }
   ```

   1. `visited` is used as a bitmask to indicate if a node has been visited
   2. `sssp` is a `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>` where the 1st hashmap's key is the source node and the key for 2nd hashmap is the destination. So it basically represent the 2D table u see in point 1.
   3. `memo` is just what I used in dynamic programming as a "cache" of previously computed shortest path from a node, given a visited bitmap.

Full source: **http://pastie.org/5171509**

The test case that passes:

```
1

3 3
1 2 3
0 20 51 35
20 0 30 34
51 30 0 12  
35 34 12 0
```

Where 1st line is the number of test cases. 3rd line (`3 3`). The 1st `3` is the number of nodes, 2nd 3 is the number of required nodes. 4th line is the list of required nodes. Then the rest is the table of edge weights.

The test case that fails is:

```
9 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 42 360 335 188 170 725 479 359 206
42 0 402 377 146 212 767 521 401 248
360 402 0 573 548 190 392 488 490 154
335 377 573 0 293 383 422 717 683 419
188 146 548 293 0 358 715 667 539 394
170 212 190 383 358 0 582 370 300 36
725 767 392 422 715 582 0 880 704 546
479 521 488 717 667 370 880 0 323 334
359 401 490 683 539 300 704 323 0 336
206 248 154 419 394 36 546 334 336 0
```

I got 3995 but the answer is 2537... sorry I know this is hard to debug ... I am having the same problem, the test case is too large ... at least for humans ... so I am creating smaller test case to test but they seem to pass ...

Comment: Could you be more specific on what problem you actually experience? What do you get (output) that indicates a problem?

Comment: what kind of test case did it fail? +1 to above comment

Comment: @cctan, Origin, updated the qn with the output. Basically the result is wrong... its not an error or anything like that ...

Comment: this looks like Steven Halim's CS2010 Problem Set :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not a full answer but I think it's at least pointing in the right direction: your code seems to give the results of following the paths 0->1->2->...->N->0. No real optimization seems to happen.

I reworked your code a bit to get a small failing test case:

```
int[][]mat=new int[N+1][N+1];
//original
//mat[0]=new int[]{0,20,51,35};
//mat[1]=new int[]{20,0,30,34};
//mat[2]=new int[]{51,30,0,12};
//mat[3]=new int[]{35,34,12,0};
//switched order of nodes, node 2 is now node 1
mat[0]=new int[]{0,51,20,35};
mat[1]=new int[]{51,0,30,12};
mat[2]=new int[]{20,30,0,34};
mat[3]=new int[]{35,12,34,0};
```

This produces 146 as a best path, showing that it follows the path 0->1->2->3->0 (47+30+34+35, 47 is the shortest path 0 to 1 using node 4) (all node numbers are with my order switch).

**edit**: I found the culprit after another quick look. You have the line `if (!hasVisited(visited, item))` to check if you already visited node `item`. However, visited is built up by `visit(visited, v)`, in which `v` is an index into the `shoppinglist`. `item =shoppinglist[v]` but you should use the same if you're shifting your visited vector.

You should use `if (!hasVisited(visited, v))` instead of `if (!hasVisited(visited, item))`

On an unrelated note, I'm unsure if the first step of finding the shortest paths is necessary or could influence your results. If a direct link from A to B is longer than going through other nodes (say C), then it is replaced in the distance table. If you would then use that link in your final solution to go from A to B, then you would actually be going via C, which would already be in your path (since that path is a full TSP solution). If a node can only be visited once, then this might be a problem.